# when using a logger in Maya 2018, my warning level log messages will go to the script editor, but not my debug level messages

Tags: python, maya

I am using Maya 2018 and attemoting to setup logging. My warning and error level messages appear in the script editor, but not my debug level messages. I wondered if they are going somewhere else?

```
import pymel.core as pm
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.error)

def texture_swap_core(selected_nodes):
    try:
        if number_of_selected_nodes(selected_nodes) is False:
            return False
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)

def number_of_selected_nodes(selected_nodes):
    """Count the number of selected nodes.

    :param:selected_nodes
    :type:list
    :return:True if an even number of nodes are selected
    :rtype:bool
    """
    if len(selected_nodes) % 2 == 0 and len(selected_nodes) > 1:
        logging.debug('even number of nodes selected')
        return True
    else:
        logging.error('odd number of nodes selected')
        return False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two things going on

```
 logging.basicConfig(level=logging.error)
```

is trying to telling the logger to ignore lower level errors.  In ordinary Python it would be `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)` -- however it's actually overridden in Maya in any case by default so it's not really affecting the outcome.

If you want to set the global log level in Maya, this works:

```
 import logging
 root_logger = logging.getLogger()
 root_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)  # or whatever level you want here
```

Comment: Do you usually do things like making another logger and working with file_handlers when writing scripts for Maya and logging? I think that way also will work around the Maya default logger overriding a script's logger? Are we resetting the Maya default logger here which might cause other issues with Maya, when we want it just use the debug level for the tool?  It did work great though.

Comment: Personally I tend to make a lot more loggers which I control directly rather than relying on root -- then I can turn on debug in a particular module for when debugging and not see every debug printout in the universe.   In general it's good practice not to touch the root logger without a very good reason, but since Maya messes with it behind your back this is a workaround that is effectively the same as the usual python idiom